# switch case does not work on android with max integer

Tags: android

I have recently had trouble with a switch case statement on android.
Therefore I have written the following example:

```
package com.example.testswitchcase;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final int STATE_A = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    static final int STATE_B = STATE_A - 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final int state = STATE_A;
        switch (state) {
        case STATE_A:
            System.out.println("state A");
            break;

        case STATE_B:
            System.out.println("state B");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("unknown state "+state+" (A: "+(state==STATE_A)+", B: "+(state==STATE_B)+")");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

It prints `unknown state 2147483647 (A: true, B: false)`.
(Target SDK 21, min SDK 8, executed on Android 4.0.4 and Android 2.2)

Running the same switch case statement in a normal Java project (Java 7) prints `state A` as I would have expected.

Is this a known problem?
Can I rely on a switch case statement to work when using different numbers?